# On which celestial bodies could you use the Apollo moon suits too?

Tags: apollo-program, spacesuits, medical

If you wore the Apollo lunar suit on celestial bodies other than the Moon, on which bodies would you survive (until oxygen run out)? You obviously couldn't wear them on any (recognized) planet because they'd be too heavy in the higher gravities, unless you use a lighter version like the one used for Apollo training on Earth. But you wouldn't survive on Venus in it due to the high surface pressure and heat, unless you're in its upper atmosphere 33 mi high where you don't need a spacesuit at all. I suppose you would survive on any natural satellite of Mars, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune, and on Ganymede and Callisto (while Europa and Io would be too close to Jupiter with too high radiation), and on any Main belt and Kuiper belt object, wouldn't you?

Comment: I worry about heat leakage through the bottoms of the boots on extremely cold surfaces of very low mass bodies; melting or gassifying underlying materials might propel you into oribit!

Comment: Apollo spacesuits were designed for day-side moonwalks. So they mostly needed cooling, not heating. I don't know how long the suits could keep heating in very cold environment (but it's solvable with upgraded/enlarged battery). The thermal insulation can be improved too, I suppose.

Comment: @uhoh Except for Phobos and Deimos, I mostly mean bodies with strong enough gravity to properly stand and walk on them (0.007g or more).

Comment: @Heopps Even without thermal improvement, do you think the suits would work alright on Vesta and other main belt objects other than ice dwarf Ceres (maybe even on Ceres)?

Comment: Whoa, who allowed you to publish my question on Twitter?